# C# multiple objects sharing a reference to boolean

Tags: c#, reference, led

I'm trying to find the best way to get the following behavior.....

I have an LED class that has a GUI LED control that has several properties including an "On" boolean.  I currently create many many new LED objects and place them around a form picturebox.  I want to have them all reference the same On boolean so that I can change the variable once and have them all update their state.  I was thinking about somehow creating a wrapper class and passing a reference to a single object but that won't let me change each LED objects position on the screen independently.

I think this could be done with an event that all of the LED objects subscribe but that seems like it would be slower than pointing to the same space in memory.  I am currently containing all the LED objects in a List and enumerating each one and updating the On property which is actually too slow.  I'm updating the LED status at 50ms in a timer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assume you have a shared reference (which can be made pretty easy) and you change the value (ok, in one place only). How all the objects that reference the "variable" would know that the value is changed and update their state?

Comment: You could keep a list of all LED observers with the led value and update all observers when the led changes. It can't really get quicker than that

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing now.  I basically have a list of all the LEDs that would need updated and when I need to update the ON status, I iterate through the list setting each one.  This is too slow (perhaps because of the graphics to redraw each LED on the screen?) and I need something faster.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but wont let me comment.

I was thinking something like this would do what I wanted but it does not work.  Maybe this shows what I was hoping would happen.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormTestApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Boolean state = false;  //global variable that updates everyone.

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyCheck my1 = new MyCheck(ref state);
            my1.Top = 100;
            my1.Left = 100;
            MyCheck my2 = new MyCheck(ref state);
            my2.Top = 120;
            my2.Left = 100;
            MyCheck my3 = new MyCheck(ref state);
            my3.Top = 140;
            my3.Left = 100;

            this.Controls.Add(my1);
            this.Controls.Add(my2);
            this.Controls.Add(my3);

            state = true;  //changing this one variable should causes all 3 to update to checked.  This does not work.

        }
    }

    public class MyCheck : CheckBox
    {

        private Boolean status
        {
            get { return this.Checked; }
            set
            {
                this.Checked = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public MyCheck(ref Boolean b)
        {
            status =  b;
        }



    }
}
```

I think something like this is needed because setting all the instances in a foreach loop does not get them all updated before the next 50ms tick happens.  This behavior causes sections of the LEDs on the screen to update but not all of them.

I'm envisioning an event that propagates to all the instances would also take too long but perhaps because it's an event it will happen without blocking in the timer tick event?

Comment: (a) You can always comment on your own questions - as you did above and (b) you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33586739/edit) the code and clarifying details into the actual question